# Chromatic number of a graph after a vertex is deleted from it.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

What happens to the chromatic number of a graph, G, when one of its vertices, v, is deleted? By this I mean what will be the chromatic number of the subgraph G-v? I know that the chromatic number can remain the same or decrease by one but I do not know how to prove this. Can the chromatic number ever decrease by 2? If not how could I go about proving that it does not?

Comment: Might be easier to think of it the other way around. How much can the chromatic number increase when you ***add*** a vertex?

Comment: Thankyou, that was a useful hint. So obviously the chromatic number can only increase by one or stay the same when you add a vertex... so it can only stay the same or decrease by one when you delete a vertex. So a formal proof of this could be by first considering the chromatic number of G-v and then relating it to the chromatic number of G?

Comment: Sounds like a promising approach.

Answer (score 1):

You want to prove that if we remove a vertex $v$ from the graph $G$, its chromatic number reduces by at most 1.  By way of contradiction, suppose $\chi(G) = k$ and $\chi(G-v) \le k -2$.  One way to color $G$ is by first coloring $G-v$ using $k-2$ or fewer colors and then by assigning a new color to vertex $v$.  This gives a proper coloring of $G$ which uses $k-1$ or fewer colors, a contradiction.

Comment: Did you read the comments on main from 12 hours ago before posting this?

Comment: Yes, but the obvious proof that came to my mind was to remove rather than add a vertex.

Comment: Exactly what is explained in the comments.

Comment: @Did I must not have read the main comment carefully enough.